# Move files from Sharepoint to HotFolder

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, filepath, email-attachments

I have emails with excel files attached that go to a Sharepoint site as well as a folder path  to that sharepoint site on my desktop.  I then take these excel files and drop them into a "Hotfolder" which essentially has a rake task sitting behind it that syncs these excel attachments every few minutes into a DB.

I'm curious if there is any functionality to get the files from the Sharepoint site to drop into that specific "Hotfolder" network file path, without me having to transfer the files myself manually.  I am pretty new to Sharepoint functionality, so any ideas would be appreciated..

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide more information about "Hotfolder". What product is that?

Comment: I'm sorry.  I am speaking about a folder that a DB has access to that "fires" every few minutes and grabs everything in it and syncs it to the Database.  It essentially is a folder that has a rake task from a DB running on it, if you are familiar with rake tasks.  Think of it as a FTP site that a database is syncing off of.

Comment: What it does doesn't really change anything, I just want to drop the Sharepoint excel files into a Network file path.  That make sense?